# Can I transfer 3DS stuff from one SD Card to another

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

What will happen if I remove my loaded 4GB SD CARD from my 3DS XL and put it into another 3DS/3DS XL? (Because when you take out the SD card, everything that is on it stays in the SD card, but not in the 3DS System and when you put it back in the 3DS XL, it does).

So, will it have the same effect if I just move the SD Card itself into another 3DS/3DS XL?

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite figure out what you are asking. Is it:

1. What happens when you transfer the files on one SD to card to another?
2. What happens when you move the SD card from one 3DS to another?

For question 1, if you move all the files from one SD card to another and then reinsert the SD card into your 3DS there will be no difference except for the number of available blocks (assuming the one of the SD cards has more storage space than the other)

For question 2, you will lose access to all the data (digital games, DLC, game updates, themes and so on)  that is stored on the SD card on the original 3DS until you put the SD card back in. The other 3DS will not be able to access any of the SD card's data until you login to your NNID on that one.